# iOS 11 not able to disable copy paste option UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, ios11

I'm using Xcode 9 and iOS 11,  Googling to disable copy paste option but not get success.

[image]

Below what I tried:

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)) {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

And also tried:

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) || action == #selector(paste(_:)) || action == #selector(cut(_:)) || action == #selector(selectAll(_:)) || action == #selector(select(_:)){
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
```

And tried so many other codes from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UITextField+disable+copy). But did't get success. Actually I don't want to display above menu then long press `UITextField`.

Comment: you need to `override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }`

Comment: Does that method get called?

Comment: I checked your code and it work in iOS 11

Comment: @NikhilManapure - yes

Comment: @Rajesh - did you not see above selection menu that put it as image ?

Comment: I see the menu. But paste, copy, selectAll, select, cut aren't available in the menu.

Comment: I am facing same issue, Did you completed it?

Comment: I'm also facing a similar issue. Upvoted so it gets an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Tested and working in iOS 12:

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool
{
    if  action == #selector(self.paste(_:))
        ||
        action == #selector(self.copy(_:))
        ||
        action == #selector(self.cut(_:))
        ||
        action == #selector(self.select(_:))
        ||
        action == #selector(self.selectAll(_:))

    {
        return false
    }
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5 following code works for me**

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(false, animated: false)
    }
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Copy and paste this UITextView subclass**

```
public class NoEditMenuTextView: UITextView {
        override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
            super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                UIMenuController.shared.hideMenu()
            }
        }
        
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        }
        
        open override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
            return false
        }
    }
```

**Then, set your text view or textfield to be a NoEditMenuTextView instead of a UITextView.**

```
@IBOutlet var myTextView: NoEditMenuTextView!
```

**Note: If you created your textview in storyboards then you'll also have to change the class there as well, in the inspector window.** (see photo)[image]